# Close the activity on grid item click android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-gridview

I have a activity which displays the `gridview` to the user 
I want to close this activity when the user clicks on the `Textview`present in the cell .How can i achieve this ?The onclick method for this text view is implemented inside the getview() method of the custom adapter .

Comment: implement onItemClickListener and finish it..

Comment: The issue is each grid view contains a Textview .Onclick() is implemnted on the textview .This on click method of the textview is present inside the getview() method of custom adapter . So I am not able to call the finish() method in the adapter

Answer (score 2):

Try using this

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
    {
        YourActivity.this.finish();         
    }
});
```

Comment: The issue is each grid view contains a Textview  .Onclick() is implemnted on the textview .This on click method of the textview is present inside the getview() method of custom adapter . So I am  not able to call the finish() method in the adapter .

Comment: So implement the `onClickListener` on all those `TextView`

Comment: I was able to implement onclick on the textview .This issue is  I am not able to close the activity .

Comment: Pass the `Activity` context in your `CustomAdapter` constructor and then use that context as `((Activity)context).finish();`

Comment: I am getting error ..java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Comment: Don't pass `getApplicationContext()` pass `YourActivity.this` in `CustomAdapter`constrctor.

Answer (score 2):

call the `finish()` method to finish the activiy

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                             finish();
            }
        });
```

Comment: @kalyanpvs Thanks i have changed

Comment: The issue is each grid view contains a Textview .Onclick() is implemneted on the textview .This on click method of the textview is present inside the getview() method of custom adapter . So I am not able to call the finish() method in the adapter

Comment: get the activity context and use

Comment: I am getting error ..java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

Answer (score 2):

In you getView()

```
View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
 {
  ////some code

  ////
  textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            YourActivity.this.finish();

        }
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement `onItemClickListener` and then finish the activity in it

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
    {
        YourActivity.finish();         
    }
});
```